# NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.util.plugin.SolrCoreAware

Tags: solr, noclassdeffounderror

I'm recreating a folder in my Solr install for our site, and unfortunately, I keep running into the following error when I try to launch Solr:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/util/plugin/SolrCoreAware
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:425)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:461)
at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:157)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:565)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.util.plugin.SolrCoreAware
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)
    ... 54 more
```

I've copied the correct jars into the lib directory of the install, however I have no idea where these classes are. Has anyone run into this issue before? Is there something else that I need to do in either the solrconfig.xml or the schema.xml? Solr launches just fine from the example folder.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with creating folder for your site?

If you want to use multiple cores for Solr, they need to be defined in [solr.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin)